# Cocos2d Spritebuilder moving sprite and firing ammo

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am going through the sprite builder tutorial and also trying to change things to see how it works and i got myself stuck and in need of help.
here's my code
The problems are marked with //<----

1. I am trying to get the little character to move right and left on the screen based on how long you press the button. 
   The best I could find through searching was is below but not as smooth as holding the button down and moving the character around.
2. All the actions appear to take place on touches ending as well, not when touched (began), how can I modify that?

   ```
   static const CGFloat scrollSpeed = 150.f;
   @implementation MainScene{
   CCNode *hero;
   CCPhysicsNode *physicsNode;
   }

   - (void)didLoadFromCCB {
   self.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;
   }

   - (void)update:(CCTime)delta {
   hero.position = ccp(hero.position.x + delta * scrollSpeed, hero.position.y);
   physicsNode.position = ccp(physicsNode.position.x - (scrollSpeed *delta), physicsNode.position.y);
   }

   - (void)jump {//make the hero jump (still deciding on 400 or 600)
   [hero.physicsBody applyImpulse:ccp(0, 400.f)];
   }

   - (void)fire {  
   CCNode* ammo = [CCBReader load:@"Ammo"];
   ammo.position = ccpAdd(hero.position, ccp(10, 20));
   // add the ammo to the physicsNode of this scene (because it has physics enabled)
   [physicsNode addChild:ammo];

   // manually create & apply a force to launch the knife
   CGPoint launchDirection = ccp(1, 0);
   CGPoint force = ccpMult(launchDirection, 8000);
   [ammo.physicsBody applyForce:force];
   }

   - (void)left { <---- How can I make the hero move based on how long the button is pressed?
   CGPoint moveDirection = ccp(-1, 0);
   CGPoint force = ccpMult(moveDirection, 8000);
   [hero.physicsBody applyForce:force];
   }

   - (void)right { <---- How can I make the hero move based on how long the button is     pressed?
   CGPoint moveDirection = ccp(1, 0);
   CGPoint force = ccpMult(moveDirection, 8000);
   [hero.physicsBody applyForce:force];
   }

   - (void)retry {
   // reload this level
   [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene: [CCBReader loadAsScene:@"MainScene"]];
   }
   - (void)exit {
   CCScene *menuScene = [CCBReader loadAsScene:@"MenuScene"];
   [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:menuScene];
   }

   @end
   ```

Comment: I would need to see the Method that you are using to call your Method Left... However to make the button action executed on begin instead of when done use the Method: '-(void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event'

Comment: that code above is all the code i have so far…

Comment: on the MainScene constructor add this line:
'[self setIsTouchEnabled:YES];
And just go and add this method:
-(void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event'
Then you should be able to make the Sprite do what you want on touch began. I am assuming you are not using CCMenuItem for buttons and just using the touch feature. 

Note: Just ADD the method, implement it, you don't have to use it. the App will do that for your automagically.